# How we match form input value with custom match sequence

Tags: javascript, regex

There is a matcher `var matcher = 'NNN#DDD'`. In this N stands for letters (a-z or A-Z) and D stands for digits (0-9).

Is there any way to match user input with the above matcher in javascript/jQuery?

For example:

```
var user_input = 'abc#123' # matched
var user_input = 'ab1#123' # non matched
```

Note: since matcher would be user input, matcher can't be changed as regular expression

Comment: a regex would do this in a snap

Comment: i know regex and everything. it's something challenging

Comment: If you know regex why not use it? Your sequence here is trivial: `/([a-zA-Z]){4}#([/d]){3}`

Comment: we need user to give input matcher sequence, it would be pain admin to say give regular expression. Above matcher would be simple sequence

Comment: If the user inputs the matcher, then you need to have some defined language/format for them to provide it in. Either you define your own (perhaps something simpler than regex) or just force them to provide a regex. If you have your own defined format, you would then convert it into a regex for internal use.

Comment: "*… numeric(a-z or A-Z)*". I don't see how that's numeric, perhaps you meant "alphabetic"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: After the question was clarified, it turns out the matcher needs to be input by a user. If you really don't want to require a regular expression from the user (perhaps because you want it simpler?) then I suggest you define your own format rules for what the matcher can be like. Then, you should convert the string they input to a regex for internal use.

For example, if the user can allow letters, numbers, or certain special characters, you could define it as (using your example): "Enter N to represent each character, D to represent each digit, and any special characters from the following set: (% #)."

If the user entered "NN#DDD%ND", you would convert that string to a regex.

```js
var userMatcher = 'NN#DDD%ND';
var matcherRegex = '';

var matcherMap = {
  'N': '[a-zA-Z]',
  'D': '[0-9]',
  '#': '#',
  '%': '%'
};

var regexValue;
for(var i in userMatcher) {
  regexValue = matcherMap[userMatcher[i]];
  
  if(regexValue === undefined) {
    throw new Error('Invalid matcher!');
  }
  
  matcherRegex += regexValue;
}

matcherRegex = new RegExp(matcherRegex);

var testInput = ['ab#123%H2', 'a1#123%H2'];

for (var i = 0; i < testInput.length; i++) {
  if (testInput[i].match(matcherRegex)) {
    console.log(testInput[i] + ' matches!');
  } else {
    console.log(testInput[i] + ' doesn\'t match...');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you would like to mask [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)?

```
<input type="text" id="masked" />
```

and just invoke the plugin:

```
 $("#masked").mask("aaa#999");
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/KegvIln8P7qa80BPRwW7